# Why does the Rockstar Social Club not track all collectables?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, rockstar-games-social-club

The Rockstar Social Club tracks various collectible items making 100% checklist easier:

- Strangers and Freaks
- Random Events
- Letter Scraps
- Spaceship Parts

[image]

However it doesn't track other collectibles such as:

- Submarine Parts
- Under the Bridge
- For sale signs

Why is this and is there an alternative way of tracking these without manually having to do it?

Comment: This actually does appear to be asking about developer intent, which would be off-topic. Do you have any reason to believe that there's an objective answer to this that doesn't require the developers to have said why?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why Rockstar neglected to track everything in Social Club, but it is a bummer.  The worst offender (IMHO) is the Stunt Jumps.  There's no indication that you've already done a jump, and if you haven't done one, sometimes you can jump pretty much successfully and not trigger it.  So it's entirely possible to sit and attempt a jump 50 times and not know if you're doing it wrong or if you've already done it.

For the jumps and flights, I used the [IGN GTA5 map](http://www.ign.com/maps/gta-5/los-santos-blaine-county) and wrote down the numbers of the jumps/flights as I completed them.  It's still a very manual process, but it's the best I could come up with.